# Excel VBA is changing the Range I set

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to set the following Range:

```
Range("F3:F102,J3:J102,N3:N102,R3:R102,V3:V102,Z3:Z102,AD3:AD102,AH3:AH102,AL3:AL102,AP3:AP102,AT3:AT102,AX3:AX102,BB3:BB102,BF3:BF102,BJ3:BJ102,BN3:BN102,BR3:BR102,BV3:BV102,BZ3:BZ102,CD3:CD102")
```

I tried to build it iteratively using a For Loop and `Application.Union`, instead of typing the Range manually because I have to build many ranges like that one.

```vb
Sub Build_Range()

    Dim FirstParamCol, ParamCells                             As Range
    Dim i                                                     As Integer

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False 'avoid infinite loop if any target cell is changed

    Set ParamCells = Range("F3:F102") 'There 20 different "Parameter" columns, the first one being Column F (column 6)
    
    'Note: After column F (6), the other 19 columns are 4 columns apart each (j/10, N/14, ...)
    'so I looped for i = 1 to 19 and used the formula column = 6 (column F) + i * 4:
    
    For i = 1 To 19 'There are other 19 "Parameter" columns
        Set ParamCells = Application.union(ParamCells, Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6 + 4 * i), ActiveSheet.Cells(102, 6 + 4 * i)))
    Next i
    MsgBox ParamCells.Address 'TODO: For Debugging only
    Range("B103").Value = ParamCells.Address
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

I get the following range, which is missing the last column ("CD3:CD102"):

```
Range("F3:F102,J3:J102,N3:N102,R3:R102,V3:V102,Z3:Z102,AD3:AD102,AH3:AH102,AL3:AL102,AP3:AP102,AT3:AT102,AX3:AX102,BB3:BB102,BF3:BF102,BJ3:BJ102,BN3:BN102,BR3:BR102,BV3:BV102,BZ3:BZ102")
```

I tried increasing the last i value in the For Loop, but I get the same range as above.

I tried the following code to Set the range manually. I get the same range as above, again missing the last column:

```vb
Sub Build_Range_2()

    Dim ParamCells                             As Range
    
    Set ParamCells = Range("F3:F102,J3:J102,N3:N102,R3:R102,V3:V102,Z3:Z102,AD3:AD102,AH3:AH102,AL3:AL102,AP3:AP102,AT3:AT102,AX3:AX102,BB3:BB102,BF3:BF102,BJ3:BJ102,BN3:BN102,BR3:BR102,BV3:BV102,BZ3:BZ102,CD3:CD102")
    MsgBox ParamCells.Address
    Range("B103").Value = ParamCells.Address
  
End Sub
```

I searched to see if it was a limit in the maximum size of a Range or something similar but I couldn't find anything.

I'm printing the built Range on a MsgBox and on Range("B103").Value, for debugging purposes only (I do not need to display the Range but to use it / work with it).

Comment: Have you tried taking the full range then using just what you need, like F3:CD102…

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First the good information is that your code building that range works properly!

Insert a `ParamCells.Select` and check what it selects. Even `"CD3:CD102"` does not show up in the address `ParamCells.Address` it is part of the range `ParamCells`.

The issue is that `.Address` is limited to 255 characters.

You can easily check that if you compare

```
Debug.Print ParamCells.Address
Debug.Print ParamCells.Address(False, False)
```

```
$F$3:$F$102,$J$3:$J$102,$N$3:$N$102,$R$3:$R$102,$V$3:$V$102,$Z$3:$Z$102,$AD$3:$AD$102,$AH$3:$AH$102,$AL$3:$AL$102,$AP$3:$AP$102,$AT$3:$AT$102,$AX$3:$AX$102,$BB$3:$BB$102,$BF$3:$BF$102,$BJ$3:$BJ$102,$BN$3:$BN$102,$BR$3:$BR$102,$BV$3:$BV$102,$BZ$3:$BZ$102
F3:F102,J3:J102,N3:N102,R3:R102,V3:V102,Z3:Z102,AD3:AD102,AH3:AH102,AL3:AL102,AP3:AP102,AT3:AT102,AX3:AX102,BB3:BB102,BF3:BF102,BJ3:BJ102,BN3:BN102,BR3:BR102,BV3:BV102,BZ3:BZ102,CD3:CD102
```

The first has 253 characters and adding `CD3:CD102` to the string would exceed 255, therefore it is truncated. The second has no absolut address and therefore it is shorter so in the end you can see `…,BZ3:BZ102,CD3:CD102` that `CD3:CD102` is actually in the range.

So any time you work with `ParamCells` it works with the full range no matter what `ParamCells.Address` is truncated to.

So the question is do you need to show the address? Then you would need some workaround (depending on what your actual goal is). Or was it only to debug your code then use `ParamCells.Select` to check it.

If you want to output the actual address of `ParamCells` vor verification, you can do that by looping through the `ParamCells.Areas`.

```
Dim AddrOfParamCells As String
Dim Area As Range
For Each Area In ParamCells.Areas
    AddrOfParamCells = IIf(AddrOfParamCells <> vbNullString, AddrOfParamCells & ",", vbNullString) & Area.Address
Next Area

Debug.Print AddrOfParamCells
```

Note that this address can only be used for verifying but you can not use it to build a range like `Set TestRange = Range(AddrOfParamCells)` because it exceeds 255 charaters.

Comment: Thanks a lot PEH. I imagined there was some kind of limit but couldn't find documentations about it, nor imagined that the limit was on .Address but the range was actually being built correctly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The .Address is limited to 255 characters... But you can handle using a String.

```
    Sub Build_Range()

    Dim FirstParamCol   As Range
    Dim ParamCells      As Range
    Dim i               As Integer
    Dim StrRange        As String 'String to store the address of ParamCells

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    'Is not a good practice to hard code... but it is your code, and
    'You will debug this... in the future!
    Set ParamCells = Range("F3:F102")
    StrRange = ParamCells.Address(1, 1, xlA1, 0, 0)
    'To find some help in .Address:
    'https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.address
    
    For i = 1 To 19
        'Here you store the address.
        'Again, don't like to hard code... but the & "," & in this point it is necessary
        StrRange = StrRange & "," & Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6 + 4 * i), ActiveSheet.Cells(102, 6 + 4 * i)).Address(1, 1, xlA1, 0, 0)
        'I Keep youy var, if you want to do something with the range.
        'You can not print the full address in the immediate window, but
        'You can still use the full range.
        Set ParamCells = Application.Union(ParamCells, Range(ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6 + 4 * i), ActiveSheet.Cells(102, 6 + 4 * i)))
    Next i
    
    'Just to check if is working.
    'ParamCells.Select
    
    MsgBox ParamCells.Address 'TODO: For Debugging only
    'No use this
    'Range("B103").Value = ParamCells.Address
    'Use this:
    Range("B103").Value = ParamCells.Address
    
Exitsub:
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  
End Sub
```

Comment: Well I think OP wanted to verify if the range was built properly and building a seperate `StrRange` is useless then, if you actually want to debug/check if your loop built `ParamCells` properly. Because you verify the string but not the range. • A better way would be to loop through all areas of `ParamCells.Areas` and get their address concatenated to a string. This way you proof that `ParamCells` is the actual range. See my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Elbert. As PEH says in his comment, a separate StrRange won't work for me since I need the Range. and just needed to verify it was built correctly. Should had PEH no replied before, your answer would have also allowed me to figure what was going on since you also mention that .Address is limited to 255 characters, so I upvoted your answer. Thank you anyway for taking the time to provide an answer!